# Random image generator without duplicates C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a poker project. I am trying to generate random cards from a file without there being any duplicates. It is like a 5 card draw type game, I just don't want it to be possible to get a 5 of a kind, or a pair of two cards that are in the same suite.

Here is a look at my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
        CardDisplay[i] = getRandomImage();
}

if (!IsPostBack)
{
        Discard.Enabled = false;

        PokerCard1.Enabled = false;
        PokerCard2.Enabled = false;
        PokerCard3.Enabled = false;
        PokerCard4.Enabled = false;
        PokerCard5.Enabled = false;

        Hold1.Visible = false;
        Hold2.Visible = false;
        Hold3.Visible = false;
        Hold4.Visible = false;
        Hold5.Visible = false;

        PokerCard1.ImageUrl = Path.Combine("/My_Portfolio/App_Themes/Portfolio/Images/Poker/", CardDisplay[0]);
        PokerCard2.ImageUrl = Path.Combine("/My_Portfolio/App_Themes/Portfolio/Images/Poker/", CardDisplay[1]);
        PokerCard3.ImageUrl = Path.Combine("/My_Portfolio/App_Themes/Portfolio/Images/Poker/", CardDisplay[2]);
        PokerCard4.ImageUrl = Path.Combine("/My_Portfolio/App_Themes/Portfolio/Images/Poker/", CardDisplay[3]);
        PokerCard5.ImageUrl = Path.Combine("/My_Portfolio/App_Themes/Portfolio/Images/Poker/", CardDisplay[4]);
}

public string getRandomImage()
{
    string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(MapPath("/My_Portfolio/App_Themes/Portfolio/Images/Poker/"));
    string CardToShow = fileNames[rand.Next(fileNames.Length)];
    return Path.GetFileName(CardToShow);
}
```

The get random image method is obviously where I call the images from the file.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like

[image]
Thanks, and any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Simplest way is to check that you don't already have the returned value in the previously gotten cards. A robust algorithm would put all cards in an array, shuffle it and take five first cards.

Comment: In the real world, you have a deck of cards, which you shuffle, and then deal from the top of the deck. You should probably stick with that model.

Comment: I think you should listen to Preston and mimic the real-world process instead of rethinking / "outsmarting" the process. It may help you later on. Eg. if each card is an object, could have "location" property or similar (which player is holding it, or in discard pile, or in deck, etc). If cards get reshuffled (I don't know if that happens in poker), you would re-randomize all the items in the discard pile, and you would know there's no cards left in the deck, etc.

Comment: Instead of getting a random image for each card in the player's hand, simply use a single list of cards, sort it in a random order, and take the first 5 cards for each hand.  
This way, you can create a multi player game where you guarantee that no card ever shows up twice.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve this would be to create a variable that holds all your current "picks", and check against that before returning a card from your getRandomImage method, something like this:

```
private List<int> _elections = new List<int>();

private string[] _fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(MapPath("/My_Portfolio/App_Themes/Portfolio/Images/Poker/"));

public string getRandomImage()
{  
    int currentPick;
    while (true){
        currentPick = rand.Next(_fileNames.Length);
        if (!_elections.Contains(currentPick)){
            _elections.Add(currentPick);
            break;
         } 
    }
    string CardToShow = _fileNames[currentPick];
    return Path.GetFileName(CardToShow);
}
```

Notice that I extracted your filenames variable so you don't recalculate your files everytime you hit the getRandomImage method.

Comment: Hello thanks a lot for your help, as I do appreciate it.  I did modify the code to more of what you have, but it still have me some duplicates, maybe not right away but after with it for a bit.  Maybe there is another option thanks for any help